# Show @click="" only if isAdmin() is true without repeating myself. Getting syntax error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel framework here. I have a checkbox that when clicked calls a javascript (Vue.js) function but it should only do it if the person logged in is admin. I have @admin directive and also isAdmin() helper function to determine if the person is an admin. But how could I write this without having to repeat myself twice for input field?

Looks like one problem is that I am writing {{ }} inside another {{ }} and another problem is escaping single and double quotes.

Here is my code where I am repeating myself twice with  field. I would like to change this.

```
@admin
   <input @click="save({{ $_GET["user_id"] }}, '{{ $_GET["date_from"] }}', '{{ $_GET["date_to"] }}')" type="checkbox" class="my-class green">
@else
   <input type="checkbox" class="my-class green">
@endadmin
```

I would like to be able to do change the above code to like this. But I end up with a syntax error.

```
<input {{ ( isAdmin() ) ? '@click="save({{ $_GET["user_id"] }}, '{{ $_GET["date_from"] }}', '{{ $_GET["date_to"] }}')" : '' }} type="checkbox" class="my-class green">
```

Syntax Error

```
syntax error, unexpected '?' (View: /var/www/php7/resources/Views/index.blade.php)

<input <?php echo e(( isAdmin() ) ? '@click="save({{ $_GET["user_id"]); ?>, '<?php echo e($_GET["date_from"]); ?>', '<?php echo e($_GET["date_to"]); ?>')" : '' }} type="checkbox" class="my-class green">
```

Comment: Are you missing a close `'` after `'@click="save({{ $_GET["user_id"] }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a ternary operator if you won't have an `else` condition.

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    class="my-class green"
    @if(isAdmin()) @click="save({{ $_GET['user_id'] }}, {{ $_GET['date_from'] }}, {{ $_GET['date_to'] }})" @endif>
```

I would try something like this. I also like to split my `<input>` into multiple lines if it exceeds 80 characters in length. It's easier to read then.

Comment: Perfect, except I need to add @endif at the end if the click attribute. Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Oops. Totally forgot about that. Edited :)